# Upload multiple images in a angular and firebase project, It is not working in sequence

Tags: javascript, angular, image, firebase

```
  async onSubmit(formValue) {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if(this.selectedImageArray.length > 0) {  // 4 images in this array
      for (let index = 0; index < this.selectedImageArray.length; index++) {  // Loop through this image array
          await new Promise(resolve => {
              setTimeout(()=> {
                  console.log('This is iteration ' + index); 
                  var filePath = `images/tours/${this.selectedImageArray[index].name.split('.').slice(0,-1).join('.')}_${new Date().  getTime()}`;
                  const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
                  this.storage.upload(filePath, this.selectedImageArray[index]).snapshotChanges().pipe(
                    finalize(() => {
                      fileRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe((url) => {
                        formValue[`imageUrl${index+1}`] = url;
                        console.log(url);
                      });
                    })  
                  ).subscribe()
                  resolve();
              }, 3000);
          });
      }
      console.log('After loop execution');
      // this.value(formValue);
    }
  }
```

After submitting the code it will download and print 3 urls and then it print 'after loop execution' then it print 4th one I don't understand why. See here in console

[image]

see in the image line no of code execution.
What I want to execute code in sequence after all images download then after it will go out of loop.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote another version of this that hopefully works as you expect it to.

1. First we create an array of all the storage upload snapshot observables.
2. The we use concat() to run them all in sequence. (If you change from concat() to merge() they will all go at once)
3. The we use mergeMap to jump over to the getDownloadURL
4. Then in the subscribe we add the url to the formValues
5. Finally in the finalize we set the class propery "value" equal to the formValue.

   ```
   onSubmit(formValue) {

     const snapshotObservables = this.selectedImageArray.map(selectedImage => {  // 4 images in this array
       const filePath = `images/tours/${selectedImage.name.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')}_${new Date().  getTime()}`;
       return combineLatest(this.storage.upload(filePath, selectedImage).snapshotChanges(), filePath);
     });

     concat(...snapshotObservables).pipe(
       mergeMap(([snapshot, filePath]) => {
         const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
         return fileRef.getDownloadURL();
       }),
       finalize(() => {
         this.value(formValue);
       })
     ).subscribe(url => {
       formValue[`imageUrl${index+1}`] = url;
     });

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a new function for multiple file upload

```
public multipleFileUpload(event, isEncodeNeeded?: Boolean):Array<any> {
        if(!isEncodeNeeded){
            isEncodeNeeded=false;
        }
        let fileList = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < event.target.files.length; index++) {
            let returnData = {};
            let file: File = event.target.files[index];
            let myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
            returnData['documentName'] = event.target.files[index]['name'];
            returnData['documentType'] = event.target.files[index]['type'];
            myReader.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
                if (myReader.readyState == 2) {
                    returnData['document'] = isEncodeNeeded ? btoa(e.target['result']) : e.target['result'];
                }
            });
            myReader.readAsBinaryString(file);
            fileList.push(returnData);
        }
        return fileList;
    }
```

In this function event is the event of the input and the isEncodeNeeded is conversion is needed. If this is true then it convert to base64 format.
The output format is

```
[{
        "document": documentbyte,
        "documentName": document name,
        "documentType": file format
    }]
```